# Porting to WPF from WinForm, problems with the Data-Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I trying to port a WinForms project to WPF. But I am have some trouble with the Data-Binding.

My WinForms program has DataGrid which uses a column in the form Data Binding Combobox

```
His **Data** properties:
DataPropertyName **Developer**
DataSource **developerBindingSource1**
DataMember **DeveloperName**
ValueMember **Developer**
```

And next code

```
developerBindingSource1.DataSource = DT.Developer;
taskBindingSource.DataSource = DT.Task;
typeTaskBindingSource.DataSource = DT.TypeTask;

developBindObjBindingSource.DataSource = DevelopBindObj.GetBindingList(DT.Developer);
typeTaskBindObjBindingSource.DataSource = TypeTaskBindObj.GetBindingList(DT.TypeTask);
```

I use additional class for dataBinding

```
class DevelopBindObj
{
    public Developer Developer { get; private set; }
    public string DeveloperName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Developer.FIO;
        }
    }
        private DevelopBindObj(Developer Developer)
        {
            this.Developer = Developer;
        }           
    public static IBindingList GetBindingList(IEnumerable<Developer>Developers)        {BindingList<DevelopBindObj> result = new BindingList<DevelopBindObj>();
    foreach (var ee in Developers)
    {
        result.Add(new DevelopBindObj(ee));
    }
    return result;
}
```

And how can I do it in WPF?

I've tried:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="iDTypeTaskColumn"
                        Header="IDType Task"
                        Width="SizeToHeader"
                        SelectedValuePath="{Binding Source={StaticResource bindObjectsTaskViewSource}, Path=TypeTask}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Source={StaticResource bindObjectsTaskViewSource}, Path=TypeTaskName}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource bindObjectsTaskViewSource}}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=tblDevTypeTask}">
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectedValuePath` and `DisplayMemberPath` should be property names on the items in the `ComboBox`, not bindings

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="iDTypeTaskColumn"
                        Header="IDType Task"
                        Width="SizeToHeader"
                        SelectedValuePath="TypeTask"
                        DisplayMemberPath="TypeTaskName"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource bindObjectsTaskViewSource}}" 
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=tblDevTypeTask}">
```

Where `bindObjectsTaskViewSource` is a collection of objects, and each object in that collection has a property called `TypeTask` and `TypeTaskName`

Answer (score 0):

Is your `bindObjectsTaskViewSource` declared anywhere in the resources for it to be accessible this way ...
`{StaticResource bindObjectsTaskViewSource}`

If not then you should first learn basics of WPF to understand difference between `Source` as `StaticResource` and `Source` as `DataContext`.